# applying cross product (kronecker) many times

Tags: r, list, function, apply, cross-product

Suppose I have a list `list0` of length `D`, where each element is a matrix `N x T`.

I am trying to create a Kronecker product, row by row that does the following.

for(i in 1:N){

```
    dummy[,i] <-  list0[[D]][i,] %x% ...( (list0[[2]][i,] %x% list0[[1]][i,]))

            }
```

Does anyone know the smartest way to apply this function?  The below is an example where I manually type it out, but I want this for arbitrary D.

```
    set.seed(1)
    N = 2
    T = 3
    D = 4
    dummy = matrix(0,(T)^D,N)

    list0 = list()

    for(d in 1:D) {

        list0[[d]] <- matrix(rnorm(N*T,0,1),N,T)

            }

for(i in 1:N){

        dummy[,i] <-  list0[[4]][i,] %x% (list0[[3]][i,] %x% (list0[[2]][i,] %x% list0[[1]][i,]))

                }



   head(dummy)
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.15578313 -0.1783412
[2,]  0.20779959 -1.5492222
[3,] -0.08194020  0.7967800
[4,]  0.18402067  0.0737661
[5,]  0.24546573  0.6407946
[6,] -0.09679284 -0.3295669
```

Comment: Edit: My simple solution was to store each kronecker in a separate list then iterate over that after D>2, then plug it into the final matrix.  There might be a smarter solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lapply` gives a list of the ith row of the matrices and `Reduce` kroneckers them together.  The `sapply` then assembles that into the final matrix.

```
N <- nrow(list0[[1]])
sapply(1:N, function(i) Reduce("%x%", init = 1, lapply(rev(list0), "[", i, TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an array might help you here:

```
set.seed(1)
arr0 <- array(rnorm(N*T*D, 0, 1), c(N, T, D))

result <- apply(arr0, 1, function (slice) {
  xx <- slice[, 1]
  for (i in seq_len(D)[-1]) xx <- xx %x% slice[, i]
  xx
})
```

#### Output:

```
> head(result)
            [,1]         [,2]
[1,]  0.15578313 -0.178341215
[2,]  0.17432718 -0.234865849
[3,]  0.01414475  0.597377689
[4,] -0.28208921 -0.003618330
[5,] -0.31566842 -0.004765147
[6,] -0.02561305  0.012120078
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `sapply()`:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
loop={
    dummy <- matrix(0, (T)^D, N)
    for(i in 1:N){
        dummy[, i] <-  list0[[4]][i, ] %x% (list0[[3]][i, ] %x% 
                            (list0[[2]][i, ] %x% list0[[1]][i, ]))
    }
},
sapply={
    dummy2 <- sapply(1:N, function(i) list0[[4]][i,] %x% (list0[[3]][i,] %x% 
                            (list0[[2]][i,] %x% list0[[1]][i,])))
    }
)

Unit: microseconds
   expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   loop 5014.211 5190.6955 5578.7469 5320.988 5505.053 9268.179   100   b
 sapply  199.230  212.0995  278.1589  229.025  244.364 4927.115   100  a 

all.equal(dummy, dummy2)

[1] TRUE
```

I'm frankly surprised that the loop is so much slower.

Comment: Does this scale if D > 4?